# Vagrant with FreeBSD guest and Windows 10 Host fails to connect

Tags: freebsd, vagrant

Has anyone been able to see /vagrant dir on a FreeBSD vagrant box? I cannot, for the life of me get it work.

Tested on Windows 10, I imagine these problems are cross-platform however. Tested with latest version of vagrant & virtualbox as of Nov 2017:

```
vagrant init freebsd/FreeBSD-11.1-STABLE
vagrant up
```

I get the following error:

`No base MAC address was specified. This is required for the NAT networking
to work properly (and hence port forwarding, SSH, etc.). Specifying this
MAC address is typically up to the box and box maintainer. Please contact
the relevant person to solve this issue.`

Then when I add a MAC address:

`freebsd.vm.base_mac = "E82AEA3A79B0" #You can change this to your local mac address`

`freebsd: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    freebsd: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    freebsd: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    freebsd: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    freebsd: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...`

So we get further, but then when I `vagrant ssh` in, I get in, but `ls /vagrant` doesn't exist.

So I try:
`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"`

But that doesn't seem to help

Also, I get the following error:

`The configured shell (config.ssh.shell) is invalid and unable
to properly execute commands. The most common cause for this is
using a shell that is unavailable on the system. Please verify
you're using the full path to the shell and that the shell is
executable by the SSH user.`

With:

```
config.vm.provision "run",
type: "shell",
privileged: true,
run: "always",
inline: <<-SHELL
    cd /vagrant/tools
    ls
SHELL
```

Comment: Per the freebsd vagrant box packagers, you should include these lines in your vagrant file: config.vm.box = "freebsd/FreeBSD-11.1-STABLE" config.vm.guest = :freebsd config.ssh.shell = "sh" config.vm.base_mac = "YOURMACADDRESS". Try it with those, if it doesn't work consider adding your vagrantfile contents to your question

Comment: I was searching off and on for hours for any documentation to go with those boxes, where in the world did you find it? I was perusing https://app.vagrantup.com/freebsd/boxes/FreeBSD-10.4-STABLE